# Q:Sql query for tree table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with tree structure:

```
Relational structure：

car
=>Tire
       =>tireA
       =>tireB
=>meter 
       =>meterA        
       =>meterB
       =>meterC
               =>meterCC
```

```
id   product1     product2
----------------
1    car          Tire
2    car          meter
3    Tire         tireA
4    Tire         tireB
5    meter        meterA        
6    meter        meterB        
7    meter        meterC
8    meterC       meterCC
..........
..........
```

In sql query resut I need a table like:

(Use "product1 = car" to search，I need to find the bottom of tree )

```
product2
----------------------
tireA
tireB
meterA 
meterB
meterCC
```

Comment: Please explain the logic for the result set.

Comment: You forgot to ask a question. Please read [ask] for what makes an acceptable, and even good, question

Comment: sorry，The problem information has been updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your probably looking for an iterative cte.  Quite well documented if you search. See below for a quick example.  The technique is to use a common table expression that references itself.  Be careful of loops in your data though.

```
DECLARE @SearchTerm NVARCHAR(10) = N'car';
DECLARE @Table AS TABLE ( id INT, product1 NVARCHAR(10), product2 NVARCHAR(10));

INSERT INTO @Table
VALUES ( 1, 'car', 'Tire' )
,      ( 2, 'car', 'meter' )
,      ( 3, 'Tire', 'tireA' )
,      ( 4, 'Tire', 'tireB' )
,      ( 5, 'meter', 'meterA' )
,      ( 6, 'meter', 'meterB' )
,      ( 7, 'meter', 'meterC' )
,      ( 7, 'meterC', 'meterCC' );


WITH cte AS ( SELECT    1           AS level
              ,         T1.id
              ,         T1.product1 Parent
              ,         T1.product2 Child
                FROM    @Table T1
               WHERE T1.product1 = @SearchTerm
              UNION ALL
              SELECT    cte.level + 1
              ,         T2.*
                FROM    @Table T2
                JOIN cte ON cte.Child = T2.product1 )
SELECT  *
  FROM  cte;
```

Comment: You are not filtering for leaf nodes.

Comment: The operation is not smooth, and errors occur in'@SearchTerm' and'@Table AS TABLE'

Comment: @DoraDora what version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: Successful, version problem